# Model file too large for loading as byteData in Flutter (Error: NewExternalTypedData expects argument 'length' to be in the range [0..1073741823])

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi, onnxruntime

I am in the process of integrating a deep learning model within my flutter app. I want to load the model on a C++ runtime (onnxruntime) through Flutter FFI.

The model file in my assets is retrieved as a datastream and converted into a `File`.

```
modelFile = File('${modelsDir.path}/$modelName');

ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/models/$modelName');
    
await modelFile.writeAsBytes(
byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes),
);
```

The path of the file is then sent to onnxruntime and the model is loaded in C++:

```
// Loading with string path
auto sessionLocal = std::make_unique<Ort::Session>(*env, modelpath, session_options);
```

The problem I am currently running into is that I get an error when running `rootBundle.load`, indicating that the file is too large.

```
Dart Error: NewExternalTypedData expects argument 'length' to be in the range [0..1073741823]
```

Seems like `rootBundle.load` has a ~1Gb limit, the loading works without issue on smaller models.
Is there a way to be able to send the model data to my C++ process and overcome this size limit ?